# Simplify retrieving the option values for an html dropdown into a php array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I'm trying to obtain the options for drop-down html menu's and put the choices into a php array.

The dropdowns contain numerical values, indiciating the top 3 preferences for text phrases, which will be included in an email.

I have a working model for doing it, but the code seems kind of klunky and I was wondering if there were s simpler way to do this?

I start off by creating the dropdown in html:

```
<div class="first_class">
  <div class="left_col">
    <p>
      <select name="choice_2">
        <option value="0" selected>_</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Then I get the drop-down values from $_POST and put them into an array

```
$choices = array('choice_2' => $_POST['choice_2']);
```

Then I use a switch statement to associate the $choices array values with the text phrase:

```
foreach ($choices as $key => $users_choice) {
  if ($users_choice > 0) {
    switch ($key) {
      case "choice_2":
        $choices_text[$choices_index++] = "This is the phrase the user selected as his choice"
        break;
}
```

Now $choices_text is a new array with the text of the user's choices.

It works, but this seems like a really roundabout way to turn the options in the dropdown to a text phrase.

Am I missing something. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: do you really believe that  `foreach ($choices as $key => $users_choice)` has any sense? and could be executed more than 1 time? Your question is unclear. `$choices_index++` undefined an has no sense. sorry but @MikeMiller answer has much more sense. But you wrote `It works, but this seems like a really roundabout way` I can't understand how it could work. but it ALWAYS set `$choices_text[$choices_index++] = "This is the phrase the user selected as his choice"` independent of user choice posted

Answer (score 0):

Yeah bit clunky. You don't really need to reassign the post array or use a switch. What about just use the post value to index the text from your array of options? Eg

```
$text_you_want=$choices_text[$_POST['choice_2']];
```